# NullPointerException at Marker.setPosition()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, google-maps-markers

In the code below, I am getting `NullPointerException`. I understand that it means that one of the things that I am using on line 228 is null instead of the valid address. But I do not see why. Is there anything that I missed?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    LatLng xmyLL2;
    private Marker marker2;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        marker2 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                position(xmyLL2).title("ver2"));
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            double xd2 = Double.parseDouble(xstr[2]);
            double xd3 = Double.parseDouble(xstr[3]);
            xmyLL2 = new LatLng( xd2, xd3 );
            marker2.setPosition(xmyLL2);  // this is line228
    }
}
```

On `line 228: marker2.setPosition(xmyLL2);` I get the exception, and this is the stack trace:

```
MainActivity$MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(Location) line: 228
LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(Message) line: 279
LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager$ListenerTransport, Message) line: 208
```

Comment: what called onLocationChanged()? has something called onCreate() first?

Comment: the problem is likely Marker2 has not been set yet. The code does not show where it is defined, but the onCreate() method instantiates it. The onCreate() method must be called before it can be used anywhere else (unless something else instantiates it).

Comment: You should avoid using capitals at the start of variable names, they look like classes.

Comment: I've just corrected the copied code - the original did not have variables with capitals at the start. And the marker2 has been setup in the MainActivity(). No?

Comment: the entire issue is much clearer now, see my hint in comments below. if you don't figure it out i'll edit my answer after my lunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that onLocationChanged() is getting called before onCreate().

If you have control over these, make sure you call onCreate first. If you do not have control, you can use `if null` so as to avoid the exception, and hope it will be called again later, after onCreate has done its magic.

change the line to:

```
if (null != marker2) marker2.setPosition(xmyLL2);  // this is line228
```

Comment: You are right. marker2 was not set. I'll set some beakpoints and let you know more. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you've gotta wonder why location is changing before it's even created... (hint: what is the order of calls for `googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(xmyLL2))`?)

Comment: Actualy there were 2 problems. I did not post it above, but there was - and had to be - call to locMngr.requestLocationUpdates(). Originally I called it before initializing all the vars. Stupid ha? :-). But even after I fixed that - the problem did not go away. The second cause of unfinished initailization was an exception that happened during initialization of marker2. which lead me to another question: How do I vew contents of System.err in Eclipse?

Comment: I can proceed now. Thanks A LOT for your help, Charlie.

Comment: glad you figured it out. Heres info on system.err - https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_does_System.out_and_System.err_output_go%3F. If you use maven or similar package/build manager, you can get output on eclipse console view